# Basic pagination with primeNG

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng, primeng-datatable, p-table

I'm using for the first time primeNG with Angular and I need to implement a basic paginated table that will show 10 rows at the time.
I managed to get the data from the API and insert them into a `p-table` but i can't understand how to properly show the first 10 rows of data because i implemented the `onLazyLoad` callback like this:

```
nextWarnings$: Observable<WholeEarlyWarningsPaginatedList> | undefined;


loadNextWarnings(event: TableLazyEvent) {
    if (event.rows) {
      this.nextWarnings$ = this.warningService.earlyWarningsList({
        offset: event.first + event.rows,
        limit: event.rows,
      });
    }
```

As you can see the problem is "`+ event rows`" that will eventually show the next 10 results at first (and I will lose the first 10).
I think I'd need a way to understand if I'm in the first page so that i will set the `offset` just to: `0`

This is the event i receive: https://primeng.org/table
You will find it under onLazyLoad

This is the Object i created:

```
export interface TableLazyEvent {
  first: number;
  rows?: number;
  sortField?: string;
  sortOrder?: -1 | 1;
  filters: unknown;
  globalFilter: unknown;
  multiSortMeta: unknown;
}
```

Maybe there's a clever solution or a better way to implement the pagination?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass event.page in API. Please try below code,

```
loadNextWarnings(event: TableLazyEvent) {
  if (event.rows) {
    this.nextWarnings$ = this.warningService.earlyWarningsList({
      offset: event.first == 0 ? 0 : event.first + event.rows,
      limit: event.rows,
    });
  }
}
```

For more details, please refer [this](https://primeng.org/paginator) prime-ng paginator documentation.

Comment: I don't have the "page" field in the event i receive from the "onLazyLoad". Can you please explain how can i get it from the paginator? I updated the question with some datas, thanks Aman

Comment: @Unearthly I've update my answer. Please try this

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because when I click on the second page i get "20" instead of "10".
Actually I didn't think about it, but it looks like it's working without the "+ event.rows" part since that's the offset of "10" that makes the error.